# Memory Warnings on iPad, but only when running through instruments

Tags: ipad, memory, instruments

I'm working on an app that works fine on all devices (all the way back to 3.0 and the first iPhone in fact). If I profile useing'Activity Monitor' instrument (Memory Monitor) tool the app runs fine, with no crashes, and no excessive memory usage reported.

However, when I run it in Profile mode with the 'Allocations / leaks' tool selected, on iPad 1, I get lots of memory warnings in quick succession followed by a crash (about a second after all the memory warnings fire off, it crashes), but this ONLY happens when running with the allocations / leaks monitor enabled.

I need to find out why this is happening. Is there a compatibility issue with iPads and the latest version of instruments and that specific tool? Does it take up an excessive portion of memory?

Thanks in advance,

Stew